# Error saving image when minimize the program

Tags: vb.net

I want to save an image using a save file dialog.Then it appears and I save the image,but when I minimize the program I receive the following error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Parameter is not valid.
I use this code and image saves but I have the error.

```
   If SFD.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        Using bitmap As Bitmap = DirectCast(PictureBox1.Image, Bitmap)
            Using NewBitmap As New Bitmap(bitmap)
                NewBitmap.Save(SFD.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
```

Comment: You are disposing the picture that is held in a picturebox. You should replace that code with `DirectCast(PictureBox1.Image, Bitmap).Save(SFD.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg)`.

Comment: Or just `pictureBox1.Image.Save(SFD.FileName, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)`. Do you want to change format if the ImageFormat doesn't match the Dialog's Filter choice?

Comment: BTW, it's more important how the Image ended up in your PictureBox than what you use to save it. The original Image Type also counts.